# Getting an "expected identified" error when it perfectly on an IDE

Tags: c

I'm using SSH Secure Shell to run and submit my assignment.  I'm getting this error right now:

`In file included from a1ms4.c:15:0:
contacts.h:37:4: error: expected identifier or â(â before â--â token
In file included from contacts.c:16:0:
contacts.h:37:4: error: expected identifier or â(â before â--â token`

Which is bogus because the exact same code compiled on another IDE.  These are my C files that are reporting the error.  I am not missing a ( or a { or a ; anywhere in my code.  I went through this code for hours to find a potential mistake but couldn't spot anything and despite that, it won't let me submit my assignment.

a1ms4.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>
#include "contacts.h"

int main(void)
{
    struct Contact contact;

    printf("Contact Management System\n-------------------------\n");

    getName(&contact.name);

    getAddress(&contact.address);

    getNumbers(&contact.numbers);

    printf("\nContact Details\n---------------");

    printf("\nName Details");

    printf("\nFirst name: %s", contact.name.firstName);

    printf("\nMiddle initial(s): %s", contact.name.middleInitial);

    printf("\nLast name: %s", contact.name.lastName);

    printf("\n");

    printf("\nAddress Details");

    printf("\nStreet number: %d", contact.address.streetNumber);

    printf("\nStreet name: %s", contact.address.street);

    printf("\nApartment: %d", contact.address.apartmentNumber);

    printf("\nPostal code: %s", contact.address.postalCode);

    printf("\nCity: %s", contact.address.city);

    printf("\n");

    printf("\nPhone Numbers:");

    printf("\nCell phone number: %s", contact.numbers.cell);

    printf("\nHome phone number: %s", contact.numbers.home);

    printf("\nBusiness phone number: %s", contact.numbers.business);

    printf("\n");

    printf("\nStructure test for Contact using functions done!\n");

    return 0;
}
```

contacts.c

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

#include "contacts.h"

void getName(struct Name *name) {
    char one;
    struct Name temporaryName;

    printf("Please enter the contact's first name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryName.firstName);
    printf("Do you want to enter a middle initial(s)? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &one);

    if (one == 'y' || one == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's middle initial(s): ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryName.middleInitial);
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's last name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryName.lastName);

    *name = temporaryName;

    return;
}

void getAddress(struct Address *address) {
    char two;
    struct Address temporaryAddress;

    printf("Please enter the contact's street number: ");
    scanf("%d", &temporaryAddress.streetNumber);

    printf("Please enter the contact's street name: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryAddress.street);

    printf("Do you want to enter an appartment number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &two);

    if (two == 'y' || two == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's appartment number: ");
        scanf(" %d", &temporaryAddress.apartmentNumber);
    }

    printf("Please enter the contact's postal code: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryAddress.postalCode);

    printf("Please enter the contact's city: ");
    scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryAddress.city);

    *address = temporaryAddress;

    return;
}

void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers) {
    char three, four, five;
    struct Numbers temporaryNumbers;

    printf("Do you want to enter a cell phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &three);

    if (three == 'y' || three == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's cell phone number: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryNumbers.cell);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a home phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &four);

    if (four == 'y' || four == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's home phone number: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryNumbers.home);
    }

    printf("Do you want to enter a business phone number? (y or n): ");
    scanf(" %c", &five);

    if (five == 'y' || five == 'Y') {
        printf("Please enter the contact's business phone number: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryNumbers.business);
    }

    *numbers = temporaryNumbers;
    return;
}
```

contacts.h

```
/* -------------------------------------------
Name:
Student number:
Email:
Section:
Date:
----------------------------------------------
Assignment: 1
Milestone:  4
---------------------------------------------- */

struct Name {
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7]; 
    char lastName[36];
};

struct Address {
    int streetNumber;
    char street[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};

struct Numbers {
    char cell[21];
    char home[21];
    char business[21];
};

//This is a structure that includes the 3 previous structures.
struct Contact {
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};
```

Comment: Where do you declare Name?

Comment: Sorry about that.  Its up there.

Comment: Are you sure the version of `contacts.h` you uploaded matches the version shown here?  I suggest checking it.

Comment: contacts.h doesn't even have 37 lines.

Comment: It actually does have 37 lines.  I omitted some of it because it was just comments.

Comment: The error message has a line number, 37, and, by omitting lines from contacts.h, you have prevented us from seeing which line is number 37.

Comment: Everything is up there.  But if you must know, line 37 is jus this }; at the end of the last struct.

Comment: Examine contacts.h carefully and see if there are some extra characters on the last line. They may be abnormal or invisible characters. Even if you cannot see them, delete the last two lines and retype them.

Comment: I've found the error.  There were dashes in the WinSCP file for some stupid reason.  Anyways, thanks a lot.  However another problem is that I am getting an "implicit function" error for the functions I am declaring in contacts.c and using them in a1ms4.c.

Comment: @OnurOzbek You need to declare them in a `.h` file that is included in *all* of the `.c` files that reference them.  Remember, each `.c` file is compiled in isolation.  If a `.c` file doesn't see a declaration, then the declaration has no effect.

Comment: That's what I have though.

Comment: Both .c files have `#include "contacts.h"` declarations.

Comment: But there are no function declarations in `contacts.h`.  All you have there are structure definitions.  Look at the names in the error message.  They tell you *exactly* what's missing.  For instance, if `getName` is referenced, then you need to add `void getName(struct Name *name);` to `contacts.h`.

Comment: Where in the contacts.h do I add them?  At the beginning of the file or after each corresponding struct?

Comment: @OnurOzbek You can add them anywhere, as long as the required data type definitions are available at the time you declare them.  It's probably simplest to just put them all at the end though, after all of the structure definitions.

Comment: Code that builds with one IDE but not another does not mean an error message is bogus.   Some IDEs tolerate certain errors of character encoding better than others but, as a rough rule, the IDEs (or compilers they invoke) that are LESS tolerant are often more correct in adherence to requirements of the C standard.    Problems like you describe are related to some host systems requiring a newline to precede an end-of-file marker, and other systems not requiring that.  Some IDEs primarily support one system type or another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regarding `contacts.h`

it is missing the multiple include guard.

```
#ifndef CONTACTS_H
#define CONTACTS_H
....
#endif // CONTACTS_H
```

it is missing the prototypes for the functions in contacts.c

```
void getName(struct Name *name);
void getAddress(struct Address *address);
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers);
```

The contacts.h file should look like the following:

```
/* -------------------------------------------
Name:
Student number:
Email:
Section:
Date:
----------------------------------------------
Assignment: 1
Milestone:  4
---------------------------------------------- */

#ifndef CONTACTS_H
#define CONTACTS_H

struct Name
{
    char firstName[31];
    char middleInitial[7];
    char lastName[36];
};


struct Address
{
    int streetNumber;
    char street[41];
    int apartmentNumber;
    char postalCode[8];
    char city[41];
};


struct Numbers
{
    char cell[21];
    char home[21];
    char business[21];
};


//This is a structure that includes the 3 previous structures.
struct Contact
{
    struct Name name;
    struct Address address;
    struct Numbers numbers;
};


// prototypes for functions in contacts.c
void getName(struct Name *name);
void getAddress(struct Address *address);
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers);

#endif // CONTACTS_H
```

After making the above changes to contacts.h, the code cleanly compiles

Comment: Your `#ifndef CONTACTS_H` `#define CONTACTS_H` are causing undefined errors.

Comment: @OnurOzbek,  Did you remember to insert the line: `#endif` at the end of the contacts.h file?

Answer (score 1):

The error:

```
error: expected identifier or â(â before â--â token
```

suggests that you most likely have an invalid character that is unrecognized by the compiler in your code that occurs in a pattern `X...stuff...X` (where `X` represents the unrecognized character).

The line being complained about is:

```
scanf(" %[^\n]", temporaryAddress.street);
```

The likely cause of the problem is you have included (copied/pasted or otherwise somehow acquired) a unicode or html variation of `'"'` (double quote) surrounding your `scanf` *format string*. (this is a common occurrence when a `#ldquo;` or `#rdquo;` (*left-double-quote* or *right-double-quote*) is accidentally included in your source file).  Most likely the result of a copy/paste of `" %[^\n]"` from some web page. Go double check that your double quotes are all `ASCII 0x22 (decimal 34)` characters.

The error is not apparent in your code above (most likely because in your copy/paste to stack overflow the funky quotes were lost in translation)

The only errors you need to fix in your code (not including all little nits, etc.) are:

```
a1ms4.c: In function ‘main’:
a1ms4.c:12:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getName’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    getName(&contact.name);
 ^
A1ms4.c:14:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getAddress’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 getAddress(&contact.address);
 ^
a1ms4.c:16:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘getNumbers’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
 getNumbers(&contact.numbers);
 ^
```

Which you remedy by including your function declarations from `contacts.c` in `contacts.h`, e.g. include the following at the end of `contacts.h`

```
void getName(struct Name *name);
void getAddress(struct Address *address);
void getNumbers(struct Numbers *numbers);
```

Your code then compiles fine -- without error or warning (well done).

The only other thing that stands out is you should initialize `struct Numbers temporaryNumbers` in `contacts.c`. Not knowing if you are compiling on Win7 with VS 10 or on a later version, simply using the C89 compatible initializer as follows works:

```
struct Numbers temporaryNumbers = {{0},{0},{0}};
```

Your code then compiles fine, e.g.

```
cl /nologo /Wall /wd4820 /Ox /Fecontacts /Tc a1ms4.c contacts.c
```

(the `/Fecontacts` just telling the compiler to create `contacts.exe` as the executable name)

(**note:** you can create a `bin` and `obj` directory to place the executables and object files in to keep your source directory clean. Just add `/Foobj/ /Febin/contacts` after `/Ox` to place all object files in `obj` (the `/Fo` option) and create the `contacts.exe` executable in `bin` (the `/Fe` option), the `/wd4820` just disables the compiler reporting the number of padding bytes added to each struct as a warning)

If you do create and use the `bin` and `obj` subdirectories, then your compile string in full would be:

```
cl /nologo /Wall /wd4820 /Ox /Foobj/ /Febin/contacts /Tc a1ms4.c contacts.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.  You and the user above really helped.  If you think my question was well asked, do you mind giving me a thumbs up?

Comment: Sure. It is a frustratingly common problem for those getting into programming (and for those very experienced few working on character-sets). Any time you are bounding between the web, windows and Unix/Linux, if you run into something odd like this, chances are it is a character-set, byte-order-mark, or end of line (DOS CRLF, verses everyone else LF) problem.